# Usando o valor de um datapicker em outro

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Estou tentando usar esse `DataPicker` para pegar o dia que ele seleciona, somar mais 7 dias e a partir destes dias, retornar só os sábados. Segue o código.
    Código atualizado, agora só falta somar os 7 dias.

```
$("#data-inicio").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 1, ""] },
    minDate: current,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#data-retorno").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $("#data-retorno").datepicker("refresh");
    }
});
   $("#data-retorno").datepicker({
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#data-inicio").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 5, ""] },    
    });
```

});

Comment: Queres essa funcionalidade quando o utilizador mudar a data ou quando a página carregar?

Comment: a variável `dateObjetc` está com o valor de uma data selecionada de outro datepicker, mas aparemente, quando vou tentar fazer outra datepicker baseado na data dessa variável, não acontece nada.

Comment: Seria alguma coisa parecida com isso? https://jsfiddle.net/ddw8ya41/ **OBS:** Não está implementada a soma dos 7 dias ainda. Só gostaria de saber se a ideia está no caminho certo...

Comment: Exemplo, o cara seleciona o dia 01/05, no meu segundo datepicker, ele só vai retornar, SEXTAS-FEIRA a partir do dia 01/05, ou seja, o minDate do segundo datepicker, tem que ser a data selecionada do primeiro datepicker.

Comment: Já consegui fazer isso aqui:

`$("#data-inicio").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 1, ""] },
        minDate: current,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#data-retorno").val(dateText);
    }
    });
       $("#data-retorno").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 5, ""] },    
        });
});`

Mas nesse script, ele joga direito no 2 datepicker o valor selecionado no primeiro, mas, no meu caso, eu queria que ele setasse o minDate do segundo com a data selecionada do primeiro.

Comment: Você olhou o exemplo que forneci no jsfiddle? Atualizei agora: https://jsfiddle.net/ddw8ya41/2/

Comment: Dei uma arrumada no seu código, agora está retornando a partir daquele dia selecionado, e como faço agora pra somar mais 7 dias? Editei minha pergunta, o código atual está atualizado.

Comment: Adicionar no minDate, dentro da função onSelect, selectedDate + 7: `$("#data-retorno").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate + 7);` aparentemente aqui funcionou certinho.

Comment: me retornou julho de 2070.

Comment: KKKK, é verdade, vi agora. Vou verificar

Comment: @MichelHenriq acredito que agora está certinho, só você modificar o resto como você necessitar: https://jsfiddle.net/ddw8ya41/3/

Comment: Só tem um porém, no meu código, o getDate do primeiro datapicker está setado para o próximo mês, e no caso, vc está dando esse getDate atual, ou seja, quando eu abro o calendário, está aparecendo pra mim o mês de Maio, mas quando eu clico, ele armazena o mês de Abril. Teria como usar o mesmo mês que está selecionado?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23256/discussion-between-rafael-withoeft-and-michel-henriq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com algumas informações passadas pelo autor através do chat, chegamos a um código com o resultado esperado pelo mesmo:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Data atual
    var current = new Date();
    //Somará 30 dias
    var aux = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth(), current.getDate() + 30);
    if (aux.getDay() != 1) {
        var nextMonth = new Date(aux.getFullYear(), aux.getMonth() + 1, 1);
        var days = Math.floor((nextMonth - aux) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

        if (days < 7) current = new Date(aux.getFullYear(), aux.getMonth(), aux.getDate() + days);
        else current = aux;
    } else {
        current = aux;
    }

    $("#data-inicio").datepicker({
        minDate: current,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', //Formato da data
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            return [date.getDay() == 1, ""]
        },
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            //Limpamos a segunda data, para evitar problemas do usuário ficar trocando a data do primeiro datepicker e acabar burlando as regras definidas.
            $.datepicker._clearDate($("#data-retorno"));
            //Aqui está a "jogada" para somar os 7 dias para o próximo datepicker.
            var data = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', selectedDate);
            data.setDate(data.getDate('dd/mm/yy') + 7); //Soma 7 dias a data atual
            $("#data-retorno").datepicker("option", "minDate", data); //Aplica a data
        }
    });
    //Segundo datepicker
    $("#data-retorno").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', //Formatação
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#data-inicio").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            return [date.getDay() == 5, ""]
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML para exemplo:**

```
<input type="text" id="data-inicio" name="data-inicio" />
<input type="text" id="data-retorno" name="data-retorno" />
```

**Em funcionamento:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ddw8ya41/6/

Comment: Fichou show cara, muito obrigado mesmo !

Comment: @MichelHenriq por nada, qualquer dúvida estamos aqui para isso.

Comment: @MichelHenriq, você precisa começar a marcar as respostas de suas perguntas como aceita. Isso ajuda outros no futuro e a comunidade :)

Comment: Só uma coisa, por exemplo, se eu seleciono uma data vamos lá: 01/06 de inicio e 12/06 de retorno, quando eu clico em inicio, só tem como opção para eu selecionar o dia 01 e o dia 08, é possivel dar um clear para o usuario selecionar qualquer segunda, caso ele queria mudar?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, eu já votei.

Comment: @MichelHenriq não é só votar que me refiro e sim [aceitar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Sobre sua dúvida, acredito que seja apenas remover o `onClose` do segundo *datepicker*, não tem necessidade de `maxDate` pelo que entendi.

Comment: Resposta aceita e arquivo alterado, funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Creio eu que tenha que fazer uma verificação, se eu seleciono o dia 22/06, ele não me joga pra julho, e eu fico em junho ainda.. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ddw8ya41/6/

Comment: O que acontece, que o minDate para o outro calendário, fica para dia 29. O que você pode fazer é, alterar o número de meses exibidos adicionando esse parâmetro: `numberOfMonths: 2,`, acredito ser a forma mais fácil e prática para não encher de verificações. Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ddw8ya41/8/

Comment: @MichelHenriq, veja [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/ddw8ya41/9/) se é isso.

Comment: isso mesmo, Valeu !